# Firefox URL given preference over keyword bookmarklet

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, bookmarks, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet saved in Firefox, with a keyword assigned. When I want to execute the bookmarklet on a page, I hit ctrl-L, type the keyword, and hit enter.

Until recently, this worked as expected. Now, it loads the first hit in my browser history that matches the keyword, as if I don't have a bookmark defined for that keyword at all.

If I type the keyword, hit escape (hiding the auto-suggestion dropdown), and then enter, the bookmarklet executes as expected.

You can reproduce this by creating a bookmark in Firefox:

```
Name: foo
Location: javascript:alert('hello');
Keyword: a
```

Load a webpage, google.com for example. Click on the address bar or hit ctrl-L. Type `a` and hit enter. Observe the browser take you to whatever in your history matched `a`.

Go back to google.com, hit ctrl-L, `a`, escape, enter. Observe the bookmarklet execute.

I am aware of `about:config`'s `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` - somewhat comically, if I change this to `false`, the bookmarklet is *displayed* in the address bar, but not executed.

This is on Firefox 68 dev edition. I started noticing this behavior somewhat recently, though I can't remember the first time it happened. Maybe within the last month or few. How can I get the old behavior back?

Edit: after some further testing, this doesn't happen in regular Firefox 67. Was there some setting that changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox. Bugzilla report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1552141

The full ticket is too much to copy here, but it was opened 2 months ago, and looks like there is already a fix being tested.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in FF 68esr and in FF 69.